# javascript multiline match after a certain string

Tags: javascript, regex, match

In this text:

```
my-Word: Value-1
othertext
my-Word: Value-2
othertext
my-Word: Value-3
...
```

I need to match all the strings that contain: `([A-Za-z0-9-]+)`

and that are only after the string: `my-Word:`, but not including: `my-Word:`

so I need to match only: `Value-1`, `Value-2`, `Value-3`, etc.

How can I do it?

Comment: combine both the regexes, `my-Word:\s*([A-Za-z0-9-]+)` . Get the value from group index 1.

Comment: @AvinashRaj can you post an example please? I can't make it working..

Comment: @user3542686: Can you show the code you're trying

Answer (score 1):

you can use positive lookbehind:

```
(?<=my-Word:\s*)([A-Za-z0-9-]+)
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?<=my-Word:\s*)([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/: Invalid group

Comment: @Mohamadshiralizadeh your regex is a lookbehind.

Comment: @Mohamadshiralizadeh i mean it is not a lookahead :)

Answer (score 0):

Use capturing groups to capture alphanumeric characters which are present just after to `my-Word:`

```
> var s = "my-Word: Value-1\nothertext\nmy-Word: Value-2\nothertext\nmy-Word: Value-3"
undefined
> var re = /my-Word:\s*([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/gm;
undefined
> var m;
undefined
> while ((m = re.exec(s)) != null) {
... console.log(m[1]);
... }
Value-1
Value-2
Value-3
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use a **lookbehind** regex, such as:

```
.(?<=my-Word: [A-Za-z0-9-])[A-Za-z0-9-]+
```

but unfortunately javascript does not support lookbehind, so you with a trick you can use a **lookahead** regex instead. for this you need to first *reverse* original string and at last the matched part:

```
[A-Za-z0-9-]+(?= :droW-ym)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hG3bO1/7)

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /.(?<=my-Word: [A-Za-z0-9-])[A-Za-z0-9-]+/: Invalid group